# How to put arrows in the axis label which are parallel to the axis line

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

```
    [X,Y] = meshgrid(1:0.5:10,1:20);
Z = sin(X) + cos(Y);
surf(X,Y,Z)
xlabel('Non dimensional stiffness \rightarrow','FontSize',13.5, 'FontName','Rockwell','Rotation',0);
ylabel('Non dimensional mass  \rightarrow','FontSize',13.5,'FontName','Rockwell','Rotation',0);
zlabel('Dimensional frequencies  \rightarrow','FontSize',13.5,'FontName','Rockwell');
```

I am facing some difficulty in labeling x and y-axis with arrows. I know how to put arrows but don't know how to rotate so that it remains parallel to the axis line all the time

Comment: I do not know in your matlab version, but in my 2018a I need to write `$\rightarrow$','interpreter','latex',`.
However, I don't know how to rotate them so that it remains parallel to the axis line all the time...